# Bluetooth not detected rfkill list doesn't show bluetooth

Tags: networking, wireless, bluetooth, dell, xps

```
*-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC
   vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 01
   serial: 44:1c:a8:e2:e6:75
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.35.177.61 firmware=01-ea662a8c ip=10.0.0.79 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:137 memory:dd800000-dd807fff memory:dd400000-dd7fffff
```

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu? What does `sudo lshw -C network` show?

Comment: i am running ubuntu

Comment: *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: 44:1c:a8:e2:e6:75
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.35.177.61 firmware=01-ea662a8c ip=10.0.0.79 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11

Comment: Please Edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1138717/edit ) your post, and add the above information, properly formatted with the `{}` tool, so that it's readable.